# Need help in SQL for creating view. their is an error near deptCode saying "Ambiguous column name 'deptCode'."

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, select

```
ALTER VIEW v_Employee
AS
    SELECT 
        empID, empFirst, empLast, empStart, empSalary, empTitle, 
        timestamp, deptCode deptName, deptBudget
    FROM 
        Department 
    INNER JOIN 
        EMPLOYEE ON DEPARTMENT.deptCode = EMPLOYEE.deptCode
GO

SELECT * FROM v_Employee
```

`deptCode` is foreign key for the `employee` table

Comment: Look at your join criteria. `deptCode` exists in both tables. As written, the engine has no way of knowing which table's `deptCode` value to return. Best practice is to give every table a meaningful alias, then qualify _every_ column name in the select list with the table aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both tables that come into play in the query have a column called `deptCode`, hence it is ambiguous which one of them your refer to in the `SELECT` clause.

You need to *qualify* that column to remove the ambiguity (ie prefix it with the name - or alias - of the table it belongs to). Matter of fact, you should qualify *all columns*; this is a best practice when writing a multi-table query:

```
SELECT 
    e.empID, 
    e.empFirst, 
    e.empLast,
    e.empStart,
    e.empSalary,
    e.empTitle, 
    e.timestamp,
    e.deptCode 
    d.deptName,
    d.deptBudget
FROM Department d 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON d.deptCode = e.deptCode
```

Note that table using alias make the query easier to read and write.